# Gradle + Robolectric + Espresso: can't run separately

Tags: testing, gradle, android-studio, robolectric, android-espresso

I tried to adapt following template: [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle)

I use Android Studio 0.8.14 (beta).

This is my **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

configurations {
    apt
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

ext {
    daggerVersion = '1.2.2';
    androidAnnotationsVersion = '3.2';
    robobindingVersion = '0.8.9';
    jodatimeVersion = '2.5.1';
    ormliteVersion = '4.48';
    ottoVersion = '1.3.5';
    commonsioVersion = '2.0.1';
    playservicesVersion = '6.1.71';
    supportv4Version = '21.0.2';
    javaxinjectVersion = '1';
    junitVersion = '4.11';
    robolectricVersion = '2.4';
}

dependencies {
    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.1.jar', 'libs/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

    androidTestCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

    apt "org.robobinding:codegen:$robobindingVersion"
    compile("org.robobinding:robobinding:$robobindingVersion:with-dependencies") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${playservicesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportv4Version}"
    compile "com.squareup:otto:${ottoVersion}"
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:${javaxinjectVersion}"
    compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:${ormliteVersion}"
    compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:${ormliteVersion}"
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: "${commonsioVersion}"
    compile "net.danlew:android.joda:${jodatimeVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/generated/source/apt/${variant.dirName}")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to ways to run unit tests:

When I use **gradlew test** I get exceptions because all tests (also instrumentation) are executed.

When I use **Android Studio** to run a **JUnit test** I get this error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:173)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code -3
```

Comment: It is well known error from here https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin#importing-into-your-ide-intellij-or-android-studio. Unfortunately Google doesn't support Robolectric officially. Did you follow steps about modification project file by hands?

Comment: I was not able to compile my project after editing the iml file. Maybe I made a mistake. But I noticed an error in my package naming. After correcting this, I was able execute tests at least with gradlew. That's sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons, I've abandoned the above approach in favor of keeping my Robolectric tests in a Gradle submodule. You can find a blog post I wrote about why I moved in this direction and a fork of the deckard-gradle project that shows you how [here](https://github.com/jdonmoyer/deckard-gradle).